# FluentAssertions - Should().BeEquivalentTo() when the mapping expectation is different

Tags: object, types, comparison, fluent-assertions

I have two classes. `SourceDto` and `TargetModel`

```
public class SourceDto {
 public string name {get;set;}
 public bool male {get;set;}
}

public class TargetModel {
 public string name {get;set;}
 public string male {get;set;}
}
```

My mapping will return for `male` property "Male" when the `male` property of the `SourceDto` is true, else the result will be `string.Empty`.

How can I compare the content of the `sourceDto` and the `targetModel` in a test?
for example, I think I cannot use
`result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(sourceDto)`, cause of the expected result type and value is different.

How can I check it with BeEquivalentTo maybe with the options?
Thanks